# How to Target Automatic Migrations from ASP.NET MVC to SQL Server that resides in a different Folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-migrations

As the Title Says, I need to target the Automatic Migrations from the Visual Studio's Automatic Migrations to a different Database that can reside from anywhere in the Computer.

Every time I try to Migrate, it always ends up Migrating My App_Data default Generated Database instead of the one that I have for the Connection Strings. I Targeted the one on the Local Database that runs on SQL Server 2012.

My work around would be attaching the Database that is Generated by the VS to the SQL so every time it is Migrated, it is will Migrate as well cause it is just one Database.

But problem resides cause I use VS 2015 and the Version of the Database for SQL server 2012 does not support it, so I am having an error.

Plus I don't really want to resort on just a work around. It would be best to ask here to get the professionals Help.

**My Connection String In WebConfig**

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MainDB;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

**My ApplicationDbContext**

```
  public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<RobinsonsFB30.Models.GiftChequeModels> GiftChequeModels { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your `context` class describes which connection string to use (at least it should be).  Can you show us that?

Comment: I am using the Default ApplicationDbContext. I will find it and paste it in my Question

Comment: What command are you using to run the migrations? Are you changing this connection string `DefaultConnection` to the database you're trying to migrate?

Comment: No, this is the Connection that I only use. I just use the Enable-Migrations then, changed the Automatic Migrations to true before I use the command Update database. But I haven't created any Up call or Down Call. Even seeding, just the Default stuffs. But somehow, it keeps targeting the app_Data. Which is a problem for me, But I NEVER encountered this problem in VS 2013 just here in VS2015 Community Edition.